# What's wrong with setting defaultChecked via getCheckboxProps in ant design table selection?

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd

I'm using a table as a radio group. Like this:

```
<Table
  dataSource={keyData}
  columns={keyColumns}
  rowSelection={keySelection}
  pagination={false}
/>
 <Form.Item >
  {getFieldDecorator('pendingKey', {
    initialValue: data?.pendingKey,
    rules: [
      {
        required: type === 'pending_key',
        message: 'Select a key'
      }
    ]
  })(<div />) // to show eorror message
}
</Form.Item>
```

Now it really helps to set `defaultSelected` in `getCheckboxProps`:

```js
getCheckboxProps: record => ({
  defaultChecked: record.key === data?.pendingKey
})
```

But ant design shows and error message when I do that:

```
Warning: [antd: Table] Do not set `checked` or `defaultChecked` in `getCheckboxProps`. Please use `selectedRowKeys` instead.
```

What is exactly wrong with that? How can I keep the input uncontrolled and turn off this message?

Answer (score 3):

Add the `selectedRowKeys` property in `rowSelection` to set the selected row

```js
<Table
  rowSelection={{
    type: 'radio',
    selectedRowKeys: ['1'], // Use this attribute
    onChange: () => {}
  }}
  //...Omitting
/>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) For example, you can elaborate what is wrong in the question's code, as asked in the title.